# handlebars multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Here is my code:
I left out the rest of the code (make it smaller) cause it spits on a span for a paging bootstrap control.

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('pagingCode', function(label, page){

        var html = '';
        ...

        return new Handlebars.SafeString(html);
    });


    My html:

    {{#each Paging}}
        <li>
            {{pagingCode label page}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}       


    My array:

    Paging is:

    [{"label":1,"page":1},{"label":2,"page":2},{"label":3,"page":3},{"label":4,"page":4},{"label":5,"page":5},{"label":"next","page":6}]


    My html output:
    [object Object]1 [object Object]2 [object Object]3 [object Object]4 [object Object]5 [object Object]6
```

When inside the helper pagingCode page is an object and label is the valid value in the array.  Any ideas on what im doing wrong?

**Update:**
    OK it was becuase nginx was caching the page so it was using the old html file it compiled.

Comment: OK I think the problem is that the html page is being cached by nginx so im testing for that now

Answer (score 1):

My answer is posted above.  It was because the html page was being cached and it only had the one parameter of label from my previous code.  After i forced a refresh it worked as expected.